# Android SOAP null response, dump = correct XML with needed data, XMLPullParser exception

Tags: android, soap, ksoap

What is incorrect in my SOAP request using ksoap in Android if I get BodyIn response = null; Response dump = correct XML with needed data, and XMLPullParser exception:

```
expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <{https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}s:Envelope>
```

Request dump:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <v:Header />
  <v:Body>
    <XMLDataGet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <entity>persona</entity>
      <last_update_date>20140101</last_update_date>
      <country>UA</country>
      <user>someuser</user>
    </XMLDataGet>
  </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in response XML that contained `<s:Envelope xmlns:s="https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">` but not `<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">` as it should be.

So I fixed that by catching InputStream and replacing `https` with `http`

Comment: I am having this same problem right now with my code... Is there a way you can send me your code so i can look at it, I'm stuck and can't figure out what's going on... :/

Comment: @bbesase pls post a question here on stackoverflow and i'll answer it with all info u need

Comment: Sorry for the delay didn't get on all weekend. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919148/android-org-xmlpull-v1-xmlpullparserexception-error