# Android org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException error

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

Trying to do a basic web service pull and I keep getting an error:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <html>@2:44 in java.io.InputStreamReader@21f12310)
```

I have been stuck on this for 3 days now. I have looked at pretty much every example on StackOverflow but still no avail idk what else and I feel like I have looked at it so many times that I'm just over looking something now... Here is my code;

```
private final String NAMESPACE   =  "http://tempuri.org/";
private final String URL         =  "http://foo/bar/Service1.asmx";
private final String SOAP_ACTION =  "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";
private final String METHOD_NAME =  "HelloWorld";
private  String TAG              =  "SOAP";

private static String message;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
}

public void getMessage() {

        String dump;
        //Create request
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        //Create envelope
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        //envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC2001;
        envelope.dotNet = true;



        //Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        //Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {

            androidHttpTransport.debug=true;
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope );
            dump = androidHttpTransport.responseDump;
            //Get the response
            //SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            //Assign it to fahren static variable
            message = response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //tv.setText(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Then when I step through it and look at the `responseDump` it says this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-   strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-   serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-    serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you    supplied.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My code errors out at this line:

```
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope );
```

When the `Exception` catches it, this is the error:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <html>@2:44 in java.io.InputStreamReader@21f12310)
```

If anybody can help me out I would be so grateful.. this has been annoying me to death that I can not figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

You can't get html web page with soap!! And if you call a webservice you must replace your link with wsdl

> foo/bar/Service1.asmx?wsdl

Comment: I've followed a tutorial online on using `ksoap2` to access a temperature one from w3schools... and it worked just fine, so why won't this one work?'